# Graphics Startup Screen

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, boot

Every time I start up my machine, there's a startup screen for the graphics card. It should display "NVIDIA GeForce 6200 VGA BIOS" with some other copyright information underneath it. However, it randomly changed to say "NV44A VGA BIOS." I think the GeForce 6200 codename is NV44A or something, but is there someway to change it back to say "GeForce 6200 VGA BIOS" or, if not, to completely stop it from showing upon startup?

My graphics drivers are all up to date.

**Machine specs:**

- AMD Athlon XP 2400+ @ 1987 MHz
- 2x 512MB PC3200 DDR RAM
- 160GB IDE HDD
- NVIDIA GeForce 6200 AGP 128MB
- FIC AM37
- Windows XP Professional SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it bothering you? This message gets displayed only a few seconds at boot.

Anyway, you can change the BIOS with the nVidia Bios Editor, [**NiBiTor**](http://www.mvktech.net/index.php?option=com_remository&func=fileinfo&id=3164).

Load a .ROM file or extract the BIOS from your card (Tools - Read BIOS).
Go to the Boot Settings tab, you can change the text to anything you want.
Once satisfied, save it and flash the BIOS to your card.

[image]

***Warning: changing the wrong settings could brick your graphic card !!!! Do not flash a modified BIOS if you're not confident it will be OK.***

Comment: Where would I find this ROM?

Comment: It's probably safer to extract it from your card (using Tools - Extract BIOS). I found one for the screenshot here: http://www.mvktech.net/component/option,com_joomlaboard/Itemid,34/func,view/catid,13/id,45979/

Comment: I don't exactly know where I would "extract it from my card"...

Comment: for the third time: go to menu Tools - select Extract BIOS

Comment: Sorry I didn't have access to my computer at the time and I was confused.